# Overriding the android:id attribute with <include> doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, include

According to the documentation, if I set an id to the `<include>` tag in an XML resource file, then it should override the id of the included layout's root view. However, it doesn't seem to work.

I created a very simple project to demonstrate it :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/merge_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**merge_layout.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Now if I run this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.button) == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("button is null"); // Never happens
    if (findViewById(R.id.test) == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("test is null");
}
```

then it throws the second exception every time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You managed to work around the problem because your included layout happened to be a ViewGroup type, which can be a xml root element. If that wasn't the case - i.e you only had a TextView in it, you would **need** to use the merge tag, and unfortunately the problem would show up. Fact is, include cannot override the id of a layout xml that has merge as root, as seen in LayoutInflater sources below... It makes the merge tag less useful :(

```
if (TAG_MERGE.equals(childName)) {
// Inflate all children.
rInflate(childParser, parent, childAttrs, false);
} else {
//...
// We try to load the layout params set in the <include /> tag.
//...
// Inflate all children.
rInflate(childParser, view, childAttrs, true);

// Attempt to override the included layout's android:id with the
// one set on the <include /> tag itself.
// While we're at it, let's try to override android:visibility.
```

Comment: Why is this not supported? Would it be too complicated or not even possible to implement this in LayoutInflater? Maybe someone could post a patch here: https://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html. I do not quite understand the way LayoutInflater inflates the Views recursively nor have the time to learn it, but if someone could it would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was pretty obvious, I misunderstood how `<merge>` works. I thought that this tag was mandatory but it isn't. The result is that the `android:id` was applied to the `<merge>` tag instead of the `<LinearLayout>`.

Removing the `<merge>` tag solved the problem.